# Clementine does not play after update to Xenial

Tags: sound, music, gstreamer, clementine

After the update, Clementine does not want to play music any more. A dialog with this error pops up (the bold font is added):

> GStreamer could not create the element: **gsettingsaudiosink**. Please make sure that you have installed all necessary GStreamer plugins (e.g. OGG and MP3)

I have tried searching for solution. One of them suggested removing some registry cache files, which I did, one `~/.gstreamer-0.10` and another in `~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0`.

After I have tried the above and failed, I found that it was possible to get some debugging output from gstreamer by setting up `GST_DEBUG=4` environment variable. With this I can see similar message in the logs:

```
0:00:04.516526128 15284      0x1ab2800 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:457:gst_element_factory_make: no such element factory "gsettingsaudiosink"!
```

It basically shows the same as the dialogue message. It does not make things any clearer to me.

What else am I supposed to do to make this work?

**UPDATE**

It seems that nuking some parts of `.cache`, `.config` and `.local` has helped. Unfortunatelly I am not sure which part made it work again as I have deleted most of it.

Comment: FWIW what helped in my case seems to have been the removal of gstreamer 0.10 and installation of the appropriate plugins for 1.0, but since the problem appeared just on one of two desktop systems I have, I can't really confirm this.

Comment: Deleting ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0 solved the issue for me. Although the error message was different: "Gstreamer is missing a plug-in"

Answer (score 1):

Removing this directory worked for me to get rid of the error:

> rm $HOME/.config/Clementine

UPDATE: After further inspection, the problem comes from the Clementine config file "*$HOME/.config/Clementine/Clementine.conf*"

You can either erase the file, or if you want to keep your seetings, simply remove the GstEngine section within the file. Here's what mine was looking like:

> [GstEngine] 
>  
>   sink=gsettingsaudiosink 
>   device= 
>   rgenabled=false 
>   rgmode=0 
>   rgpreamp=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\0\0\0\0) 
>   rgcompression=true
>   bufferduration=1000 
>   monoplayback=false

I've opened an issue on github for the Clementine developers:
https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/5378